# Best practices: adding two event listeners to event where one listener requires a passed parameter and the other does not

Tags: typescript, events, event-handling

Might be a simple question, but I have an event, lets call it `addObject`. I emit this event and I have two listeners for it. One listener requires an "important object" const to be passed through but the other does not. So I have something like

```
myFunction1() {
  const importantObject = {...};
  // other logic
  this.emit('addObject');
  this.emit('addObjectWithParam', importantObject);
}

myFunction2() {
  //other logic
  const forceUpdate = this.forceUpdate.bind(this);
  this.addListener('addObject', forceUpdate);
}

myFunction3() {
  this.addListener(
    'addAuditTest',
    this.handlerFunction.bind(this),
  );
}
```

It seems like breaking an abstraction barrier by emitting 'addObject' twice, but I do this, because `forceUpdate()` takes no parameters, but I need `importantObject` in `handlerFunction()`.

What is the cleanest thing to do here/best practices?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a higher level question but I will try to answer as best as I can.

Simply the question that I would ask myself is from "business" or "domain" perspective are they the same event or not.

In terms of events / event handling it shouldn't matter whether a listener needs the arguments of an event. What matters is what the events themselves are.

Take an example of an event `onSelect`. Now this event will happen every time a user changes a dropdown field. It will pass through the new value that the user has selected.

I have two consumers:

1. Calling an api with the users selection. This will require the selected value
2. Calling an analytics api that the user has changed their selection. This may not require the selection value.

In this case if a consumer doesn't care they simply ignore the argument. We don't have to provide different events for the same `onSelect`.

However, you need to make sure they really are the same. Another example is that of `onMouseUp` vs `onClick`.

The `onClick` event may not have an argument as it's simply informing that the user has clicked a button. Where as the `onMouseUp` might have information about the mouse location or what not.

They can both be used to detect a click but they are fundamentally different events.

You just need to figure out if they are the same event with different consumer needs or the same event.